# Is there an interactive Python-based environment similar to Mathematica?

Tags: python, environment

I am teaching art students the basics of Python and it would be very convenient to add some graphics (drawings, pictures, etc.) in the comments within the code instead of "just" code and text comments.

I have seen some friends using Mathematica and exchanging beautiful files that include graphics, comments, pictures, etc.

Does such a thing exists for Python?

Comment: do you mean [IPython](http://ipython.org/) and [Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/) ?

Answer (score 2):

Have you looked at the iPython-Notebook? It allows you to write/run code and use html for notes. If you know html it will be easy to add graphics in too. Not sure if that exactly answers your problem, but it is definitely a nice tool

Link: http://ipython.org/notebook.html